# Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices of order $2\times 2$, where $\det(A)=1$ and $\det(B)=2$ then value of $\det(A+\alpha B)-\det(\alpha A+B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

Let $A$ and $B$ be two square matrices of order $2\times 2$, where $\det(A)=1$ and $\det(B)=2$ then value of $$\det(A+\alpha B)-\det(\alpha A+B)$$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is

(A)$\alpha^2$

(B)$0$

(C)$\alpha^2-1$

(D)None of these

**My Attempt**

Let A be the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} and $B$ be the matrix \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}
Substituting in the expression $\det(A+\alpha B)-\det(\alpha A+B)$, I am able to get $\alpha^2-1$.

When I took $B$ to be the matrix \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} I again ended up getting $\alpha^2-1$.

But is there some general way to go about it.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be the two eigenvalues of $X=A^{-1}B$. Then $\lambda\mu=\det X=2$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\det(A+\alpha B)-\det(\alpha A+B)
&=\det(A)\left[\det(I+\alpha A^{-1}B)-\det(\alpha I+A^{-1}B)\right]\\
&=\det(I+\alpha X)-\det(\alpha I+X)\\
&=(1+\alpha\lambda)(1+\alpha\mu)-(\alpha+\lambda)(\alpha+\mu)\\
&=(1+\alpha\lambda+\alpha\mu+2\alpha^2)-(\alpha^2+\alpha\lambda+\alpha\mu+2)\\
&=\alpha^2-1.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Use the [property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688492/let-a-and-b-are-square-matrices-of-order-2-with-real-elements-such-that-ab-a/4688582#4688582) for $2\times 2$ matrix $M, N$

> $$|M+xN|=|M|+x^2|N|+x\left[\text{Tr}(M)\text{Tr}(N)-\text{Tr}(MN)\right]$$

We have:
$$|A+\alpha B|=|A|+\alpha^2|B|+\alpha\left[\text{Tr}(A)\text{Tr}(B)-\text{Tr}(AB)\right]$$

$$|B+\alpha A|=|B|+\alpha^2|A|+\alpha\left[\text{Tr}(B)\text{Tr}(A)-\text{Tr}(BA)\right]$$

Note $\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)$, then we have:

$$|A+\alpha B|-|B+\alpha A|=|A|+\alpha^2|B|-|B|-\alpha^2|A|=\alpha^2-1$$

Comment: For a proof of a similar property which can be used, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4616011/129912) here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a &b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}e &f\\g&h \end{bmatrix}$. Since Det$(A)=1$, we have that $ad-bc=1$ and since Det$(B)=2$, we have that $eh-fg=2$. Now
$$A+\alpha B=\begin{bmatrix}a+\alpha e & b+\alpha f\\c+\alpha g&d+\alpha h\end{bmatrix}, ~ \alpha A+B=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha a+e & \alpha b+f \\\alpha c+g&\alpha d+h\end{bmatrix}.$$ Therefore
$$Det(A+\alpha B)-Det(\alpha A+B)\\=\left((a+\alpha e)(d+\alpha h)-(b+\alpha f)(c+\alpha g)\right)-\left((\alpha a+e)(\alpha d+h)-(\alpha b+f)(\alpha c+g)\right)\\
=((ad-bc)+\alpha^2(eh-fg))-(\alpha^2(ad-bc)+(eh-fg))\\
=(1+2\alpha^2)-(\alpha^2+2)=\alpha^2-1.$$